# Recover some old features without losing new changes?

Tags: git

Let the following sequence be a linear sequence of commits with independent change modifications:

```
start -->  change 1 --> change 2 --> change 3 (current state)
```

Now, let's say that `change 1` was a total screw-up and we want to go back to our start commit with respect to the parts altered by `change 1`, but without losing the independent `changes 2` and `3`.

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just revert the unwanted commit?

```
$ git revert <revision>
```

This will keep `change_1` in history and will commit a `change_4` that undoes `change_1`.

Answer (score 2):

`git revert` commit 1.
You may need to resolve conflicts if the commits are somewhat dependant.